# Recall value from an array in C

Tags: c

I'm new to programming and attending a course in C. We learned how to create an array of values and it's all good. Now we have to recall a certain value from the array using scanf(). Now we didn't get explained how to do that and I guess they are expecting us to figure it out ourselves but I have now spent the whole day 'figuring out' without success. I just don't understand. Now I'm not asking to solve the problem for me but at least explain the rule and I can then write the code. I've read all about arrays in C and I understand what it is and how it works but nowhere I could find explanation about this problem. This is my sample code. I create an array with 3 variables of type int. I store 3 values using for loop. Now I need to recall for example index 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int values [3];
    int i=0;
    for (i=0; i<3; i++){
        scanf("%d", &values[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "recall a certain value from the array using scanf()" - `scanf` does the exact opposite - it _writes_ data to memory, but it looks like you want to _read_ data from the array. `scanf` is for _input_, but "recalling" implies _output_.

Comment: What do you mean (or think they mean) by "recall a value"?  I can think of a couple of possibilities.  One: print the value in a given element of the array (or otherwise access it): `for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) printf("%d: %d\n", j, values[j]);`.  The other is to find the index of an entry that contains a given value: `int x = 37; bool found = false; for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) { if (values[j] == x) { found = true; printf("%d: %d (%d)\n", j, values[j], x); break; } } if (!found) printf("Value %d not found\n", x);` — give or take any typos (and adding `#include <stdbool.h>` to the headers).

Comment: Hi there by recalling I meant requesting the program to retrieve a stored value according to its index location. So arrays stored as 0, 1, 2, 3, n.. Each index location has a value stored (int in my case). Now after storing those values I want to retrieve the values stored under ind 1 for example.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a value from an array goes the same way for inserting and reading from it.

```
int index;

scanf("%d", &index);

printf("%d", values[index]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This above looks like path to solution and I know that I somehow have to connect index with the values but I am completely stuck. In my case I have values[i], is it wrong? Because then 'i' is kind of my index, no?

Comment: Ah ok I got it through trial and error but I somehow still struggling to understand how int index in this case connects with arrays. Can anyone explain? Here is my solution code: [#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int array [10];
    int i, index=0, values=0;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        scanf("%d", &values);
        array[i] = values;
        index = index +1;
    }
    scanf("%d", &index);
    printf("%d", array[index]);
    return 0;
} ]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, heres is the answered code. I know it's pathetically simple and it is with the help here that I finally understood.I just couldn't understand how index integer would work but I get it now. You are basically calling a memory cell to retrieve its value through an integer. Ahh, I'm so not clever.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int array [10];
    int i, index=0, values=0;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        scanf("%d", &values);
        array[i] = values;
        
    }
    scanf("%d", &index);
    printf("%d", array[index]);
    return 0;
}
```